# apache virtual host configuration confusion

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm confused as to use virtual host or not. `domain.com/xyz/xyz` points to an external server IP address. How can I configure apache on the external server to resolve requests coming from `domain.com/xyz/xyz` to folder `xyz` (`/var/www/html/xyz`) and not the default virtual host?

Comment: What's your current configuration?  A new virtual host will only be helpful if you're looking to serve content for a different domain, not a different path.  What you're trying for should certainly be possible, but you need to clarify how you have it configured now that the content you want it to serve is not being served.

Comment: This is a temporary solution for what I need. The server that hosts domain.com/xyz does not want to host my web application, thus I asked him to point domain.com/xyz/xyz to another (external) server. I'm positive that domain.com/xyz/xyz is not being served. So my question is how do I point requests coming from domain.com/xyz/xyz to where it should go (/var/html/www/xyz not the default folder).

Comment: So there's a reverse proxy involved, too?  You really need to provide information on the configuration, we can't just guess.  Are they proxying the request to you unchanged, or is the path stripped?  What's your `DocumentRoot` set to, and what content needs to be served for what exact request?  And are both `xyz`s in `xyz/xyz` the exact same string, or are they different?